# How can I make widget "sticky" with Tkinker Canvas Create_window method?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I created a series of checkbutton with text(cb in the example), and I put them into a canvas with the create_window method (I need that because I have a Scrollbar).
How can I extend this code and get my checkbuttons sticky to left and right border?

```
canvas.create_window(0, i*20,       #for non overlapping
                     window= cb[key],
                     anchor = NW)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to compute the width of the window and specify that when you create the item.

The alternative is to put all of the checkbuttons in a frame using `pack`, `place` or `grid`, and then have a single `create_window` for the frame. That's the more common way of using a canvas to scroll a bunch of widgets.

For an example of using a frame embedded in a canvas, see this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432